# How to pass <select> option from page1 to page2 using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to pass from page1.html the selected value to the next page2.html
Page1.html :

```js
<form action="product.php" method="POST">
<select name="option">
  <option value="product">product</option>
  <option value="event">event</option>
  <option value="organization">organization</option>
  <option value="movie">movie</option>
  <option value="book">book</option>
  <option value="review">review</option>
  <option value="recipe">recipe</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="GO"/>
</form>
```

How can I create a var that will recieve the selected option on Page2.html using POST method?

Thanks,
Ofer

Comment: store the value in localstorage and you can access it on the next page.

Comment: Thanks, but since i'm a beginner, I don't know how to do it...

Comment: You can do it using [cookie](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) and [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp this will help you in understanding how to use localstorage.

Comment: You must do it using `query-string-argument` instead of `web-storage`!

Comment: Hope someone could write what should i do on page2.html in order to recieve what option was chosen on page1.html

Comment: Make a form method `GET` instead of `POST` and you can access it in the second page by [`Reading Query String`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: People have provided enough pointer for you mate! Do some search and that will be it! Good luck :)

Comment: And with `php`, Things are even easier! `$_REQUEST` will help!

Answer (score 0):

An elegant way of doing this is by using `localStorage`
You have to do a minor change in HTML & put this snippet in your `js` file

**HTML**

```
<form onsubmit = "someFunction()" > // A function which will be executed on submit
  //Rest of the code
</form>
```

JS

```
function someFunction(){
   if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") { // Checking is storage is supported
    localStorage.setItem("yourkey", "yourvalue");
   } else {
    // Take necessary action if not supported
   }
}
```

In second page

```
var _myStoredItem = localStorage.getItem("yourkey");
```

Beside using localStorage, you can also use

For example
Assume this is your url

```
http://www.myPage.com/product.php?myDate=someDate
```

and in second page

```
var myVar = window.location.search.
```

If there are multiple query parameter you have parse this query string to get the required parameter. This will require the `form method ="GET"`.Since you are using `POST` this may not be relevant to you.

Answer (score 0):

In page2, add a hidden input with the selected value posted from page1. E.g.:

```
<input type="hidden" id="selected_option" value="<?php echo $_POST['option'];?>" />
```

On page load of page2, i.e. during client side execution of page2, get the value and set it to a variable:

**page2:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var globalVar;
    function pageLoad()
    {
        globalVar = document.getElementById("selected_option").value();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="pageLoad()">
    <input type="hidden" id="selected_option" value="<?php echo $_POST['option'];?>" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I think it's either my php doesn't work or either i'm not sending (through page1.html) the value correct.